# Set div background color according to text length

Tags: html, css

I have a section on website where different testimonials appear and the div has a background color which appears fine on desktop but if viewed on mobile devices the testimonials text runs longer (vertically) than the background height.

This is the class that is assigned to the div

```
.quote{
    background-color: #f7f7f7 !important;
    border: 8px none;
    height: 350px;
    padding: 15px;
}
```

Now I know that the height is fixed to `350px` but if I change that to `100%` or `auto` that does not work. I need the background to appear as long as the text appears.

Comment: In these cases it's easier if we have a fiddler to play with, but try applying a vertical margin.

Comment: What's wrong with http://jsfiddle.net/rzp2ro5q? Removing height should make the div auto scale.

Comment: Add overflow: auto; to .quote, the floated content isn't being added to the height. See http://jsfiddle.net/vekgx3hq/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the div to be `350px` in height, then you're doing it right. But you will need to add `overflow-y: hidden;` or `overflow-y: auto`.

However, I do suggest you simply change `height` to `min-height` if you want the div to grow with the text.

Comment: i dont need it to be 350px, i will be more than happy to remove it because i just need it to cover the text in all devices, i am try the solution you mentioned and get back